# Jquery append vs appendTo rendering different results

Tags: javascript, append

How come the appendTo statement gives me the desired effect ("Hello" printed out to screen) and the append statement prints "[object Object]" to the screen. Aren't they doing the same thing?

```
log = $("<div><h1>Hello</h1></div>");
log.appendTo(document.body);
document.body.append(log);
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the last statement, you're using the [`append`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) method of the DOM object body. As the given parameter is neither a DOM Node nor a string, it is casted to as string.

You probably want

```
$(document.body).append(log);
```